# Kotlin synthetic in Adapter or ViewHolder

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am new in kotlin. I have found and tried to use synthetic method instead of annoying method `findViewById` in my `Activity` class, but I have found "If we want to call the synthetic properties on View (useful in adapter classes), we should also import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view.*." But I can't figure out how it exactly works? Is there any examples?

Comment: You can check this [blog](https://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/kotlin-android/kotlin-android-extensions-in-adapter/) or this [example](https://github.com/thedeveloperworldisyours/RoomAnko/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/thedeveloperworldisyours/mytasks/task/TaskAdapter.kt)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Simple example from https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.item_forecast.view.*

class ForecastListAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        fun bindForecast(forecast: Forecast) {
            itemView.date.text = forecast.date.toDateString()
        }
    }
}
```

No need to write

```
val view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date) as TextView
view.text = forecast.date.toDateString()
```

Just

```
itemView.date.text = forecast.date.toDateString()
```

Simple and effective!

Comment: ok, this might be a dumb question, but where does 'itemView' reference come from?

Comment: ok, I noticed that I was missing the .view. part of the import.
Now, the itemView reference is available, and it seems to come from RecyclerView.ViewHolder class in v7 support package. Tks

Comment: `itemView` is a property of the base type (`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`)

Comment: There's no cache for view extensions, so references to views should be cached, like in ordinary viewHolder.

Comment: @Mike since Kotlin 1.1.4 all views are going to be cached. Even in ViewHolders. The Article you posted does mention this as well.

Comment: @StefanMedack I am the author of the article :) Although I have to point that it is only part of the experimental features and needs to be manually enabled. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @MiguelBeltran the link to your article is no longer working

Comment: Here are some details about caching in 1.1.4 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46646302/1000551

Comment: As @Vadim Kotov has mentioned, LayoutContainer has to be implemented for views to be cached and they have to be referenced directly -> `date.text = forecast.date.toDateString()` otherwise findViewById is called each time.

Answer (score 39):

Kotling 1.1.4 out

Further information : https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

You need to enable Kotlin Android Extentions by adding this to your **build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Since this new version of Kotlin, the Android Extensions have incorporated some new interesting features: caches in any class (which interestingly includes ViewHolder)

Using it on a ViewHolder (or any custom class). Note that this class should implement `LayoutContainer` interface:

```
class ViewHolder(override val containerView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView), 
        LayoutContainer {

    fun bind(title: String) {
        itemTitle.text = "Hello Kotlin!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding to this information: As per Kotlin 1.1.4 the feature is experimental and needs to be enabled on the build.gradle file

Comment: Is this experimental any longer? I want to use this in production code

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer this feature is still experimental

Comment: seems it doesn't even work with `1.3.21`. I think they aren't going to implement it

Comment: but we can use `containerView.itemTitle.text = "Hello Kotlin!"` and I think it's enough

Comment: Is this still experimental?

Answer (score 11):

You need

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.row_wall.view.*
```

And later something along the lines of:

```
convertView.titleText.text = item.title
```

The point is that the view.* introduces extensions to the View class.

Comment: answer was already given https://stackoverflow.com/a/33428208/7767664 why did you repeat it?

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
class CustomViewModel(val baseView: View) {
    val firstName = baseView.firstName
    val lastName = baseView.lastName
}
```

View object exposes the views
ref:https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/unable-to-use-kotlin-android-extension-in-adapter-class/2890

Comment: answer was already given https://stackoverflow.com/a/33428208/7767664 why did you repeat it?

Comment: @ user924. if answer is already in another thread, please moderate and mark current thread as duplicate and add reference to other thread

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the latest version l;.you don't have to add experimental = true to it.

in Project level Gradle

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21'
```

And in app level Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' //These should be on the top of file.
```

and in dependencies..

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21'
```

and import below as

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.your_layout_file_name.view.*
```

and example

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_animal.view.*

class AnimalVH(parent: ViewGroup, layoutID: Int) : BaseViewHolder<Animal>(parent, layoutID) {

    override fun bindData(animal: Animal) {
        itemView.tv_animal.text = animal.title
    }
}
```

where BaseViewHolder is

```
abstract class BaseViewHolder<T>(parent: ViewGroup, layoutID: Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutID, parent, false)
) {
    abstract fun bindData(model: T)
}
```

Comment: Is there any official confirmation about this? I believe using `.view.*` import defeats the purpose, the fallback will be to `findViewById<>` , each time -- the very pattern a `ViewHolder` dissuades from.

Comment: Explained at: https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-android-extensions-using-view-binding-the-right-way-707cd0c9e648

Answer (score 1):

It means you have to place this line at the beginning of your source file:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view.*
```

So now instead of, for example, `findView(R.id.textView) as TextView` you would write just `textView`. The latter is a synthetic extension property located in the package `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view`, that's why you have to import everything from it.

There's a [tutorial on the official site](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), take a look.

Comment: I have seen it yet. I have do it for my activity, as I described above. But how I can use it inside BaseAdapter derivatives?

Comment: Well, basically you can invoke `findViewById()` method on a `View`, like `holder.findViewById(R.id.name)`. With Kotlin Android Extensions you can write just `holder.name`.

Suppose this code is written inside a `getView()` function: `val base = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)`
`base.name.text = "John Smith"`

Comment: But what if I have to use several view holders with various layouts? How can I realize it with synthetic? Because we have to use specific "synthetic link" for each layout and I have several layouts with similar ids.

Answer (score 0):

**FYI:** Data binding is recommended over synthetic for view lookups.

[Comment from a DA for Android from Google](https://old.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/efdvpkg/?st=jyfzj73u&sh=9b9c5a50) on Reddit

> Hey! Developer Advocate for Android at Google here!
>
> I wanted to add a bit of background here. Kotlin Extensions with
>   synthetic views was never intentionally “recommended” though that
>   shouldn’t be taken as a recommendation to not use them. If they're
>   working for you please feel free to continue using them in your app!
>
> We’ve been shifting away from them (e.g. we don’t teach them in the
>   Udacity course) because they expose a global namespace of ids that’s
>   unrelated to the layout that’s actually inflated with no checks
>   against invalid lookups, are Kotlin only, and don't expose nullability
>   when views are only present in some configuration. All together, these
>   issues cause the API to increase number of crashes for Android apps.
>
> On the other hand, they do offer a lightweight API that can help
>   simplify view lookups. In this space it's also worth taking a look at
>   Data Binding which also does automatic view lookups - as well as
>   integrates with LiveData to automatically update your views as data
>   changes.
>
> Today, there's a few options in this space that work:
>
> Data Binding is the recommendation for view lookup as well as binding,
>   but it does add a bit of overhead when compared to Android Kotlin
>   Extensions. It's worth taking a look to see if this is a good fit for
>   your app. Data Binding also allows you to observe LiveData to bind
>   views automatically when data changes. Compared to Kotlin Extensions,
>   it adds compile time checking of view lookups and type safety. Android
>   Kotlin Extensions is not officially recommended (which is not the same
>   as recommendation against). It does come with the issues mentioned
>   above, so for our code we're not using them. Butter Knife is another
>   solution that is extremely popular and works for both Kotlin and the
>   Java Programming Language. Reading through the comments here there's a
>   lot of developers that are having great luck with Kotlin Extensions.
>   That's great - and something we'll keep in mind as we look at ways to
>   continue improving our APIs. If you haven't taken a look at Data
>   Binding, definitely give it a shot.
>
> As an aside, our internal code style guide is not intended to be
>   directly applied outside of our codebase. For example, we use
>   mPrefixVariables, but there's no reason that every app should follow
>   that style.