# Can't access view in holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, anko

I'm trying to create `RecyclerView` adapter and following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#Adapter) documentation.

```
private class Adapter(private val list: List<HashMap<String, Any>>, private val ctx: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Adapter.ViewHolder {
        var mTextView: TextView

        return ViewHolder(ctx.UI {
            relativeLayout {
                mTextView = textView("1 + 1 = 2")
            }
        }.view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.mTextView.text = "1 + 1 = 3" // Should work?
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

How can I access `mTextView` in the `onBindViewHolder`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using kotlin extensions and have a text view with an id mTextView, then it should be:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.mTextView.text = "1 + 1 = 3" // Should work?
    }
```

You can also define variables in your ViewHolder and use them directly, this is the best way in terms of performance as it won't force unecessary calls to [findviewbyid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192550/how-to-bind-view-in-recyclerview-viewholder-with-kotlin/44208181#44208181):

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val myTextView = itemView.mTextView
}
```

And later access it like:

```
 holder.myTextView.text = "some text"
```

Comment: Can you give an example for a text view with an id mTextView?

Comment: The first part of the answer tells you how to access it directly, I'll post an example sing a variable

Comment: Thanks. I think my `mTextView` initialization is wrong because when I try your solution I get `Unsolved reference` in `ViewHolder`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you import you view using kotlin extensions? import kotlinx.android.synthetic.<YOUR LAYOUT FILE>.* inside the adapter?

Comment: Oh. I see what you saying. Basically, I'm creating view inside `onCreateViewHolder`. That's what Kotlin Anko does. So is there a way to pass variable name or just should I go with the oldschool way?

Comment: If you're not using android extension then findviewbyid is the way to go :)

Comment: That's what I thought. Just were looking for new ways.

Comment: Why don't you use android extensions? It's the best and most used way in Kotlin ...

Comment: I discovered [Kotlin Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) and got a project about it. So, I just don't want to use XML layouts.

Comment: It's your personal opinion that "it's the best" to use Extensions, I don't know how you know if it's "the most used way" in Kotlin. It's up to each developer / team to decide if that's the right tool for them out of [many alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44285703/4465208).

Also, in your first snippet you're actually demonstrating a common error made when using it with ViewHolders, (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208181/4465208)), while presenting it as an equal to the correct way you show afterwards.

Comment: It is indeed a personal opinion, as for the most used way I just used the web and SO as a thermometer to measure how much a technology is used, I've see loads of projects using kotlinx, but.once again it was a guess, thanks for clarifying. I'll edit my answer to include your comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing `Unresolved reference` when trying to access views in `onBindViewHolder`.

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //Unresolved reference fooView
    holder.itemView.fooView.text
}
```

In the end it turned out I was just missing the kotlinx import atop

```kotlin
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.myLayout.view.*
```

...And adding the extensions plugin in my app's build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions' //here
}
```

Adding the dependency and the `import` fixed it for me.

Comment: Wow thank you so much I have been looking for this answer forever! It fixed it for me too.

Comment: No problem @AntalGeorgina . I'd appreciate a vote up on the answer if that was useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is to create a property for your `TextView` inside your `ViewHolder`. This isn't particularly easy with Anko, but here are some ways to do it.

---

#### 1. Pass every `View` you want be able to reference from your `ViewHolder` as a separate constructor parameter.

For this solution, you have to modify your `ViewHolder` class like this, adding a property for the `TextView`:

```
class ViewHolder(view: View, val mTextView: TextView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

You can initialize this property in this slightly convoluted way:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Adapter.ViewHolder {
    lateinit var mTextView: TextView

    val view = ctx.UI {
        relativeLayout {
            mTextView = textView("1 + 1 = 2")
        }
    }.view

    return ViewHolder(view, mTextView)
}
```

While this doesn't look very nice, you're keeping the reference to your `TextView` from when you're initially creating it, so it's efficient.

---

#### 2. Give your Anko created `View` instances IDs and look them up by their IDs later.

First, you have to create constants for your IDs - the ID can be any positive number, just make sure they're unique within the scope you're using them. One way is to place these inside a companion object, like so:

```
companion object {
    private const val TEXT_VIEW_ID = 123 // Arbitrary positive number
}
```

Then, you need to give this ID to your `TextView`:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Adapter.ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(ctx.UI {
        relativeLayout {
            textView("1 + 1 = 2") {
                id = TEXT_VIEW_ID
            }
        }
    }.view)
}
```

Finally, you can find your `TextView` again in your `ViewHolder` class with `findViewById`:

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val mTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(TEXT_VIEW_ID)
}
```

Of course this is going to be slower, because you're losing the `TextView` reference you already had when you're passing in the `View` to the `ViewHolder`, and then you're looking it up again.

---

Note that I stuck with `mTextView` for the answer so that it's easier to follow, but it's generally [not recommended](https://android.github.io/kotlin-guides/style.html#naming-1) to use Hungarian notation or any other name prefixes in Kotlin.

Comment: Your first answer isn't easy like you said but it's also nice when you have few views. I'll just stick with the `findViewById` method.