# Kotlin: Type mismatch (RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm pretty new using Kotlin, I tried to port my project from java to kotlin. Basically, I have a helper class that try to init recyclerview layout, adapter and so on.

In java:
Adapter

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
  ...
  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

my helper function:

```java
public void init(RecyclerView recyclerView, boolean horizontal, boolean divider, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, Context context)
```

When I created the adapter and call the function, it works fine.

But in Kotlin:
Adapter

```java
class MyAdapter(...) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
  ...
  inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

helper function

```java
fun init(recyclerView : RecyclerView, horizontal: Boolean, divider: Boolean, adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>, context: Context) {
  ...
}
```

when I created the adapter and call the function

```java
val myAdapter = MyAdapter(...)
helper.init(listView, false, false, myAdapter, this)
```

I got mismatch error where it required: `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` and found: `MyAdapter`

Inheritance wise, it should work right? or did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call this function? The question is who is `this` in your case , activity or fragment?

Comment: hi, the "this" is refer to activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite, the correct declaration you require is:

```
class MyAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
```

and you then need to implement methods such as this signature:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder
```

etc.

`onCreateViewHolder` must return a ViewHolder or a subclass of it, e.g.

```
return ItemViewHolder(view)
```

where:-

```
inner class ItemViewHolder(val mView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView)
{
  val mFieldView: TextView = mView.field
  ...
}
```

and you can use this knowledge within the bind function, e.g.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)
{
  val itemHolder = holder as ItemViewHolder
  val item = dataModel[position]
  itemHolder.mFieldView.text = item.field
}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer, I override all the methods, but I just did not put it on my snippets. And your answer is correct, I should just inherit `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()` instead of the inner ViewHolder class. And your way  of ViewHolder and binditem is better, I just learned that Kotlin has such a easy way to do it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192550/how-to-bind-view-in-recyclerview-viewholder-with-kotlin/44208181). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the type of adapter you are using, there are different types of adapter like array adapter, recyclerView Adapter. Specifically, in list views, we use an array adapter. While with recycler View adapter used is recycler view adapter and it will show the above error if you use array adapter with recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Replace `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` with `RecyclerView.Adapter<*>`