# Do Kotlin Android Extensions cache the synthetic properties or each time it calls findViewById()?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

If I have a simple custom view:

myitem.xml

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
<FrameLayout/>
```

Accessing a kotlinx syntentic property:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.myitem.view.*

view.toolbar.text = "Some text"
```

Internally it generates a call to `findByViewID()`. So my question is:

**Is the result cached for custom views like for activities or each each time `findByViewID` is called?** The answer is quite important for performance reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 1.1.4 views can be cached in any class.
Caching in custom views enabled by default. For ViewHolders you need to implement `LayoutContainer` interface like this:

```
class MyViewHolder(override val containerView: View): LayoutContainer
```

See this doc for details
https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/android-extensions-entity-caching.md

Update:
To be able to use `LayoutContainer` you should add this to the gradle script:

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Comment: Is the proposal fully implemented in 1.1.4?

Comment: I did but I wasn't completely sure.

Comment: Has anyone tried it? I am debugging it and see that findVidewById is still getting called. ViewHolder does implement LayoutContainer and I tried to access views either `itemView.myView` and `containerView.myView`

Comment: try `viewHolder.childView`. btw these extensions are deprecated unfortunatelly :(

Answer (score 8):

In the current version (1.1.3), views are cached for Activities and Fragments layouts. For other kinds of containers like RecyclerView ViewHolders, there is no cache.

Also, the cache is a `HashMap` with Integer boxing for keys. A `SparseArray` would have been better.

Edit: Since version 1.1.4, views can be cached for other classes too, including `ViewHolder`, if you make them implement the `LayoutContainer` interface. You can also use the `@ContainerOptions` annotation to specify another cache implementation, including `SparseArray`. Both of these features are still experimental and need to be enabled manually in your `build.gradle` file:

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

[Read more](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/android-extensions-entity-caching.md) about it.