# Error "unresolved reference" in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have code:

```
package com.example.admin.maytinh

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.button
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText2
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText3


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{xuly()})
    }

    public fun xuly(){
        val a:Int = editText.text.ToString().ToInt()
        val b:Int = editText2.text.ToString().ToInt()
        val c:Int = a + b
        editText3.text = c.ToString()
    }

}
```

When i run it, i receive errors:

- unresolved reference setOnClickListener
- unresolved reference: text
- unresolved reference: ToString

Anyone can explain for me why this is so and fix it
Thank you

Comment: Where do you instantiate button? LIke button = findViewById(R.id.button)? same for editTexts

Comment: I added and i have error "unresolved reference: text", "unresolved reference: ToString"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You importing ids, not views.
Instead of:

```
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.button
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText2
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText3
```

use this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

and add plugin in app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: For RecyclerView.ViewHolder https://stackoverflow.com/a/33428208/5710872

Comment: The question is Why My Android Studio didn't it for me? Why I need to add it manually?

Answer (score 4):

You got `unresolved` error because you have not imported view. Instead of view you have imported ids.

There import To import single view

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout_name>.<view_name>;
```

or

To import all widget properties for a specific layout

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*
```

Also you need is to enable the Android Extensions Gradle plugin in your module's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html).
To do so import:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

instead of

```
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.button
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText2
import com.example.admin.maytinh.R.id.editText3
```

Spend few minutes on reading how KAE work - it will help you a lot.

Moreover, there are no such methods as `ToString()` and `ToInt()`. What you're looking for is this: `toString()` and `toInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem even after using migrating to viewBinding. It turns out that the problem was that I mistakenly gave my webview the same XML id then the layout it was in. I spent a weekend trying to solve it. I guess sharing that will be useful for someone else.

[image]

Comment: how to import  com.android.tools.lint  lint-27.2.1.jar